Android SELinux: start dnsmasq on startup
I have had this question on android.stackexchange.com for more than a month, but I just realised that my problem isn't related to Android as much as it is related to SELinux and Android security.

I’m trying filter all DNS traffic using dnsmasq on Android (LineageOS), and to let it automatically startup on boot. Here is what I did:

I installed dnsmasq using termux:
pkg i root-repo && pkg up && pkg i dnsmasq
Then:
cp /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/dnsmasq /system/bin/

On Linux it's possible to divert traffic to dnsmasq simply by editing /etc/resolv.conf and replacing nameserver 8.8.8.8 with nameserver 127.0.0.1.
But on Android there is no such file, however I can achieve the same using an iptables command (divert all DNS queries to port 5353):
/system/bin/iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:5353
/system/bin/iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:5353


I create the file /etc/dnsmasq.conf containing:
domain-needed
bogus-priv
no-resolv
no-poll
port=5353 # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< PORT
listen-address=127.0.0.1
no-hosts
expand-hosts
cache-size=500
log-queries

server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4

# Rules:
# Test block:
address=/bing.com/0.0.0.0


Now I can already start dnsmasq using the command:
/system/bin/dnsmasq --pid-file --conf-file=/etc/dnsmasq.conf <&-
I can also look at the logs and see that dnsmasq is running:
logcat | grep dnsmasq
05-27 19:17:08.039  7988  7988 D dnsmasq : forwarded google.com to 8.8.8.8
05-27 19:17:08.039  7988  7988 D dnsmasq : forwarded google.com to 8.8.4.4

But on the phone there is no internet access. This is the first problem I am having (dnsmasq has no internet access).

The second problem happens when I try to start dnsmasq on startup. Thanks to input from @IrfanLatif, I flashed Magisk, and I have access to setpriv command.
However, when I try to set a UID to dnsmasq:
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/setpriv --reuid=999 --regid=999 --clear-groups /system/bin/dnsmasq --pid-file --conf-file=/etc/dnsmasq.conf <&-
I get the error:
dnsmasq: failed to find list of interfaces: Permission denied
I also tried to start it in a script vim /system/etc/init/myboot.rc without any success. Any guidance from anyone is much appreciated.


